# Could you please tell me how can I delete the 2 symbols on my WordPress page in the picture below?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image]

The 02 symbols in the red circles, it's from the Gateway theme. I want to modify and remove these 2 symbols but I really don't know how. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: by using css you can display none of above two symbol.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Could you please explain more detail on that? I don't know how to use css but I am willing to learn. Thank you again!

Comment: please share your website link.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just know that I cannot customize the theme if I use the free WordPress plan. Thank you again!

Comment: @OceanEyes you using WordPress.com ?